# Apache SSL reverse proxy not correctly forwarding requests to non SSL hosts on localhost

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, reverse-proxy

I'm struggling to get my Apache config right.
I'd like to terminate the SSL connection on Apache and proxy to the http servers on localhost.

The setup is browser --> Apache (HTTPS) --> localhost:8001
                                        --> localhost:8002

The reverse proxy has been setup to use the context in the URL e.g. `http://url/test1` will redirect to localhost:8001/test1

I keep getting redirected back to the http port. Fixing up the protocol to https loads the page, but if I get redirected I end up back on http and not https.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

SSLCACertificateFile  /etc/XXX
SSLCertificateFile    /etc/XXX
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/XXX

SSLProxyEngine On
ServerName             url

<Proxy *>
         Order deny,allow
         Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyRequests           Off
ProxyPreserveHost       On

ProxyPass               /test1       http://localhost:8001/test1
ProxyPassReverse        /test1       http://localhost:8001/test1

ProxyPass               /test2       http://localhost:8002/test2
ProxyPassReverse        /test2       http://localhost:8002/test2

</VirtualHost>
```

My config works for non SSL connections to Apache though.

Answer (score 0):

The proxied systems are unaware of the SSL proxy, so http URLs need to be rewritten to https.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Jira and Confluence support [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Integrating+JIRA+with+Apache+using+SSL)  pattern.